# Handling dateformats

Tags: c#, date-format

I've a C#/.Net windows application.
It parses excel files received from an external source.This excel file has date in MM/dd/yyyy format.
But the format could change in the future.for eg. it could be yyyy-mm-dd or yyyyMMdd or something else.
DateTime.ParseExact requires dateformat in the input.

Is it possible to make my C# code dateformat agnostic so that I dont need to make code changes in the future?
And if yes how do I achieve this please?

Comment: Why ParseExact? TryParse will do exactly what you need...

Comment: Out of Curiosity, how would you parse 01/12/2010.  Is that January 12th or is it December 1st?

Comment: excel should be storing it as a date/number.

Comment: It would be 1/12/2010 12:00:00 AM. See it here: https://ideone.com/N9Tn5r

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for something like [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It works with any format, and if something goes wrong it will raise an exception which you can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the following DateTime methods:

- Parse: input will always be in a standard system format.
- TryParse: input may be in a standard system format.
- ParseExact: input will always be in a specific format.
- TryParseExact: input may be in a specific format.

To me, it sounds like none of them actually apply to you completely.  If you only expect one format at a time but the format may change then I would suggest using TryParseExact but storing the date format externally, e.g. in the config file.  That way, you won't have to recompile if the format changes but you also won't be relying on the format matching a standard system format.